# Creating conditionally visible sidebars in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In R and `shiny`, I would like to use tabs in `shinydashboard`. The dashboard normally has a sidebar, but for one tab I would like to sidebar to disappear to give some more screen space to the body of the page.

I know that there are conditional panels, but is it possible to adjust the visibility of the sidebar when a tab is activated?

Below is some mock code to setup the shinydashboard with three tabs and a sidebar.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  # I would like to make the sidebar not visible if the third tab is selected...
  # something like...
  #if(input.tabs==3){dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)}else{dashboardSidebar()},
  dashboardSidebar(),
  if(input.tabs==3){dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE)}else{dashboardSidebar()},
  dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        column(width=12,
               tabsetPanel(id='tabs'
                 tabPanel('tab1',
                          plotOutput('plot1'),value=1),
                 tabPanel('tab2',
                          plotOutput('plot2'),value=2),
                 tabPanel('tab3',
                          plotOutput('plot3'),value=3)
               )
        ))
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(1000)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()
    print(out)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(1000)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()
      print(out)
  })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(1000)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()
      print(out)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've never used dashboards until 5 minutes ago when I saw this question, so this might not be the best answer, but it works.

It looks like when you manually "hide" the sidebar, the `body` tag gets a "sidebar-collapse" class.  So my solution was to add javascript that adds that class to the body tag when the third tab is selected. The one downside is that when another tab is chosen, the sidebar will not re-expand, it will stay hidden until you manually expand it again.

Disclaimer: in my answer I use a package that I wrote, shinyjs.

Here is the shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs("app.js"),
    fluidRow(
      column(width=12,
             tabsetPanel(id='tabs',
                         tabPanel('tab1',
                                  plotOutput('plot1'),value=1),
                         tabPanel('tab2',
                                  plotOutput('plot2'),value=2),
                         tabPanel('tab3',
                                  plotOutput('plot3'),value=3)
             )
      ))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(1000)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()
    print(out)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(1000)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()
    print(out)
  })
  output$plot3 <- renderPlot({
    out <- ggplot(data.frame(X1=rnorm(1000)),aes(X1))+
      geom_density(fill='light blue')+
      theme_minimal()
    print(out)
  })

  observe({
    if (input$tabs == 3) {
      js$hideSidebar()
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I only added a few lines to your app: I added calls to `useShinyjs()` and `extendShinyjs("app.js")` in the UI, and I added `observe({ if (input$tabs == 3) js$hideSidebar() })` to the server. I also added the `session` parameter to the server function. You will also need to add a javascript file named "app.js" that contains this line:

```
shinyjs.hideSidebar = function(params) { $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse") }
```

You can also avoid using `shinyjs` and use shiny's normal message passing to call a similar javascript function.

**EDIT:** with the latest shinyjs version 0.0.6.1 you don't need to use a separate file if you prefer to provide the javascript code inline. Simply replace the call to `extendShinyjs("app.js")` to

```
extendShinyjs(text = 'shinyjs.hideSidebar = function(params) { $("body").addClass("sidebar-collapse") }')
```

Comment: I get the following error `Warning in run(timeoutMs) :
Unhandled error in observer: argument is of length zero
observe({
    if (input$tabs == 3) {
        js$hideSidebar()
    }
})`

Comment: Are you using shinyjs v0.0.6.0? shiny v0.12.0.9001? Did you copy exactly the code from my answer? I forgot to add in my answer (I'll edit now) that I also had to add the `session` parameter to the server function.

Comment: Realised that I needed to also have the pacakge `V8` installed as well. Is there a way to get the sidebar back when switching back to the other tabs? i.e. once the sidebar has been 'collapsed' how can i get it back when clicking on tab 2 or 1?

Comment: You can add a similar function in the javascript file: `shinyjs.showSidebar = function(params) { $("body").removeClass("sidebar-collapse") }` and then call `js$showSidebar()` when you want to show it. As I said earlier though, this will not be "smart" in the sense that it will always hide when you click on tab3 and will always expand when you click on tab1/2.  It'll get more complicated to try to have some logic that "remembers" whether the sidebar was already closed when tab3 was selected and then conditionally expand it when tab1/2 is selected afterwards. I hope that helps